# jQuery/Mootools issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, mootools

I'm working on a page that has both Mootools 1.4 and jQuery 1.5.1 running. I know this isn't ideal but I don't really have an option. The page works fine in most every browser, but not in IE8. I get the following error:

`Object doesn't support this property or method`

when attempting to add a click event, despite putting my jQuery-specific code in a noConflict block. Here's a fiddle that reproduces the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/p7rFV/1/

Thanks for any ideas on what's going on.

```
$.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });


document.getElementById('button').addEvent('click', function(){
   document.getElementById('tester').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues with your fiddle:

1. When you do, you should use `jQuery.noConflict();`, not `$.noConflict();`
2. MooTools can't enhance DOM elements at the prototype level in IE like it can in other browsers, so you have to always be sure to pass them through `$()` or `document.id()` before using MooTools-specific functions on them. So this line fails:

   ```
   document.getElementById('tester').hide();
   ```

   ...because the DOM element has no `hide` method. Instead, just use [`$()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollar) or  [`document.id()`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adocument-id):

   ```
   $('tester').hide();
   document.id('tester').hide();
   ```

   ...which will both look up the element *and* extend it.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7rFV/11/)

Comment: Thanks-- however, jQuery is being included-- see the Manage Resources tab to the left of the jsfiddle panel. I appreciate the explanation. I was under the impression that $() was shorthand for `document.getElementById` and not `document.id`

Comment: can you explain a bit more on point #1-- I've used the exact noConflict syntax recommended in the jQuery docs at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ -- I admit I'm not clear on it, but is there a better resource to look at?

Comment: @julio: If you use `$.noConflict`, you have to worry about load order and whether someone else calls it as well. If you use `jQuery.noConflict`, you don't have to worry about those things. because you're not *relying* on `$` = `jQuery` at the point of the call.